# How do I use Mox to mock a module function and allow it to be called in almost any way

Tags: python, mox

I have a function A that call another function B several times. I want to mock B in such a way that *any number* of calls that have the correct number of arguments, regardless of value, will return a fixed vale and be treated as correct.

If or how many times the the function is called is not a part of the spec.

Answer (score 8):

Stub out B normally....

Assuming B accepts 2 arguments and should return 'foo':

```
B(mox.IgnoreArg(), mox.IgnoreArg()).MultipleTimes().AndReturn('foo')
```

Comment: doesn't seem to handle the zero call case: `ExpectedMethodCallsError: Verify: Expected methods never called`

Comment: That's true, and I'm not sure how to fix it... except this is a much easier problem with 'mock' which I now use most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

```
def B(*args, **kwds):
   return 'fixed value'
```

Comment: And how do I use that with mox?: http://code.google.com/p/pymox/wiki/MoxDocumentation

Comment: You don't need Mox for this method.